# Are BelongsToMany with conditional data fields possible in Nova?

Tags: laravel-nova

I have a use case for Nova that I am not sure on how to approach. Here's how I imagine things going down: I have a generic `Product` model that would have a lot of different `Attribute` models attached to it on a many-to-many relationship basis using a pivot table. The pivot table would also tie data (possibly in JSON form) to the Attribute models.

Let's say we have an Attribute named 'volume' and it has a type of 'number'. When attaching (in Nova terms) the volume `Attribute` to the `Product`, the user would also enter a number which would then be stored in the pivot table.

Then we also have an `Attribute` named 'colour' which would have a type of 'select' and an 'options' field with a fixed list of colours. When attaching the colour `Attribute` to the `Product`, the user would be prompted to use a dropdown in which they would select a colour from a fixed list of colours.

Currently, it appears that Nova's BelongsToMany field does not allow this use case, as there's no way to do conditional logic in the `->fields()` function of the BelongsToMany field. I'm currently lost as to how I would be able to work around the limitations.

My current best idea is to either extend the BelongsToMany field (both PHP and Vue side) such that it allows for previously described conditional logic or build a "hacky" custom field that goes into the `->fields()` function which removes the original `BelongsToMany` `select` field from the DOM and replaces it with its own. The custom field would fetch the necessary data and display the corresponding data fields.

TL;DR:
I want to attach an `Attribute` model to a `Product` model and only show specific pivot fields depending on `Attribute` model's `type` value.

Anyone had similar encounters with meta/pivot fields that require additional data in Nova?